# Why this constructor doesn't give me the right answer

Tags: java, if-statement, constructor

I did a break from programming for a while and I want to realize why this class doesn't give me the right answer I expect to get:

```
public class Date
{
    private int _day;
    private int _month;
    private int _year;
    public Date(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        _day=day;
        _month=month;
        _year=year;
        if((day<1||day>31)&&(month<1||month>12)&&(year<1000||year>9999))
            {
                _day=26;
                _month=2;
                _year=2019;
            }
        }
    public String toString()
    {
        return _day+"/"+_month+"/"+_year;
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Date test= new Date(5,13,1999);
        System.out.println(test.toString());
    }
}
```

When I insert the values to "test" object as (32,5,1999) it prints out 
26.2.2019.
When I insert the values as (5,14,1999) it prints out 5.14.1999,
and when I insert the values as (5,6,900) it prints out as 5.8.900.
Why don't I get the default values that I set at the constructor when the user inputs an illegal value (26.2.2019).
Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Your if statement is if ALL THREE VALUES are bad, not just one. For what you're trying to do, you might use OR instead.

Comment: @JosephLarson you are right, now it's working.
can you give me an explanation between what i did and what you offered ?
thank you

Comment: @Idos i meant that this date will be printed if one of the values won't be legal

Comment: For (A && B) to be true, both A and B must be true. So for `(day<1||day>31)&&(month<1||month>12)` to be true, both the day and the month have to be out of range.

Comment: @daniel I think what they are saying is if you want to check if "one of the values won't be legal" use `||` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the `if (...)` statement, which only gives you the default value when **any** parameter is wrong.

For example,

```
(32,5,1999) becomes (TRUE && FALSE && FALSE) = FALSE
(5,6,900) becomes (FALSE && FALSE && TRUE) = FALSE
```

You may want to change your statement to

```
if(day<1||day>31 || month<1||month>12 || year<1000||year>9999){
...
}
```

In order to get the default date in the event of an error

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
if((day<1||day>31)&&(month<1||month>12)&&(year<1000||year>9999))
            {
                _day=26;
                _month=2;
                _year=2019;
            }
```

> will execute only if all of three conditions you specified are true.

What that means is next:
input - 26.2.2019

```
(day<1||day>31) = **false**
(month<1||month>12) = **false**
(year<1000||year>9999) = **false**
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement checks if "date & month & year" to be wrong at the same time to give the default result. You should use "||" instead of "&".

Answer (score 0):

Since you have been away from programming, you should check out the [Java Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_operators.asp).
Those you are having a problem with are the Logical Operators.

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace to default if the date and month and year separately then use like below

```
if(day<1||day>31) _day=26;
if(month<1||month>12) _month=2;
if(year<1000||year>9999)_year=2019;
```

If you want to update the date to default even if one of the entry is wrong then use

```
if((day<1||day>31)||(month<1||month>12)||(year<1000||year>9999))
{
  _day=26;
  _month=2;
  _year=2019;
}
```